# Absolute file path also throws error 'invalid path' error in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have file path from phone gallery by using package `file_picker` like below in flutter:

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/56A38F73-6433-4AA0-AB0E-0268F2EA0431/tmp/IMG_6062-1700193462304.png

I need to hold this path and shows this image after reloading app with Widget `Image.file`.

But It shows `Invalid path` error.

I realized that this is relative path so path keeps changing so it can't open file.

So I look up the way of converting relative path to absolute path.

```
Future<String> getAbsolutePath(String relativePath) async {
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

  String absolutePath = join(appDocPath, relativePath);

  return absolutePath;
}

Future<List<String>> copyImageListToAppDirList(
    List<dynamic> sourcePathList) async {
  List<String> absolutePathList = [];
  try {
    for (final sourcePath in sourcePathList) {
      String absolutePath = await getAbsolutePath(sourcePath);
      absolutePathList.add(absolutePath);
    }
    return absolutePathList;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error copying image: $e');
  }
  return [];
}
```

In `copyImageListToAppDirList` function it changes `list of relative path` to `list of absolute path`.

And I pass this absolute image path to next screen and open it with `Image.file(File(absolutepath))`

However, it still throws error Invalid path.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you pick a file from your phone's gallery in your app, it might be in a place your app can't easily reach. The app tries to change the location of this file so it can use it later, but sometimes it can't find the file because it's kept in a spot where the app isn't allowed to go.

To fix this, you need to check if the app has permission to get to this file and if the location given by the phone for the file is in a place where the app is allowed to go. If the app can't reach that spot, it won't be able to use the file. You might need to make some changes in how your app gets permission or where it looks for the file so that it's in a spot the app can access properly.

**1.**Ensure Permission:**** Check if your app has permission to access files in the selected directory. In iOS, this might require additional configuration in the `Info.plist` file to allow access to certain directories.

**2.Use Correct File Provider:** Ensure that the file provider or file picker you are using returns a path that your app has permission to access. Sometimes, the file picker returns a path that the app itself doesn't have access to due to sandboxing.

**3.Check Path Conversion:** Double-check the path conversion logic to make sure it's accurately converting the relative path to the absolute path within your app's sandbox.

**4.Error Handling:** Implement error handling to catch specific file access errors. This could help in pinpointing the exact issue, such as permission denied or file not found errors.